# Is this a bug in html 5 or am i mad?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Am i mad or is the following a bug in html 5?

Im coding something like a "game map". Its really simple, here the drawing code:

```
g2d.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            for(var i = minx; i < maxx; i++){
                for(var j = miny; j < maxy; j++){
                    var drawx = i * tileWidth + posx;
                    var drawy = j * tileHeight + posy;
                    g2d.drawImage(images["image0"], drawx, drawy);
                    g2d.fillText("x: " + i, drawx + 3, drawy + 10);
                    g2d.fillText("y: " + j, drawx + 3, drawy + 20);
                    g2d.rect(drawx, drawy, tileWidth, tileHeight);
                    g2d.stroke();
                }
            }
            for(var i = 0; i < bases.length; i++){
                var position = bases[i]["position"].split(":");
                var x = parseInt(position[0]);
                var y = parseInt(position[1]);
                g2d.drawImage(images["image1"], x * tileWidth + posx, y * tileHeight + posy); 
            }
```

its nothing special, just a grid and then the bases on their positions.
Here a demo, you can drag it around with the mouse:

[link](http://mymaksimus.bplaced.de/stuff/map1.html)

Now: I wanted to add a grid, so boxes, for easy debugging.
So i added this to lines of code in the for(for( loop:

```
g2d.rect(drawx, drawy, tileWidth, tileHeight);
                    g2d.stroke();
```

juts after the fillText() stuff.
The result is a shame:

[link](http://mymaksimus.bplaced.de/stuff/map2.html)

Its lagging around and it seems like the stuff isnt clearing. 
Whats up there? 
Anyone an idea how to fix this??

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn this:

```
g2d.rect(drawx, drawy, tileWidth, tileHeight);
g2d.stroke();
```

into:

```
g2d.strokeRect(drawx, drawy, tileWidth, tileHeight);
```

and you won't have problems with path (at the cost of a tad performance). Alternatively use `beginPath()` before you start the loop.

The reason is that the rect adds to the path and accumulates. Everytime stroke() is called everything in the path is redrawn. beginPath() will clear the path while strokeRect() is a direct rasterized method which doesn't add to the path.

Example:

```
g2d.beginPath();
for(var i = minx; i < maxx; i++){
    for(var j = miny; j < maxy; j++){
        var drawx = i * tileWidth + posx;
        var drawy = j * tileHeight + posy;
        g2d.drawImage(images["image0"], drawx, drawy);
        g2d.fillText("x: " + i, drawx + 3, drawy + 10);
        g2d.fillText("y: " + j, drawx + 3, drawy + 20);
        g2d.rect(drawx, drawy, tileWidth, tileHeight);
    }
}
g2d.stroke();
```

Comment: hm, i'll try this. Where is the difference between the two things?

Yeah its very laggy. I cannot drag the map with the grid, because its running with ≈1 .. fps?

Comment: Yeah it works, thx very much Crypto and Vision.! But why? where is the difference?

Comment: aaah okay. Thank you! 
is there something like an api for this, where one can read things like that?

Comment: @T_01 many details in the specs: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html but of course, it targets browser implementers so not everything is relevant for us users.